# Can`t play mp4 byte array as3

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, apache-flex, arrays, mp4

1. i`m getting mp4 as byte array from Socket server
2. I`m using append bytes to play video

   netStream.play(null);
                    netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
   netStream.appendBytes(recordByteArray);

But video wont play and even no meta data received.

If i play video directly from url, there is no problem, but when i receive it from socket as byte array... didn`t work. With FLV byte array there is no problems.

Any help pls

Comment: Try waiting before you'll receive first sizable chunk of video data before starting playback.

Comment: I use appendBytes when all bytes from socket are received.